# Pulseaudio recommended use

Tags: pulseaudio

How do I accomplish basic tasks with Pulseaudio, like playing a sound?

I'm finding "documentation", e.g., https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PulseAudio or http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=789578, and I'll quote from these.  But they provide more more marketing blurb than specifics.

I don't think Pulseaudio needs to be fixed -- Skype can use sound just fine.
But HOW??

"PulseAudio is an advanced sound server which has been included in Ubuntu (i.e. the standard GNOME version) since the release of Hardy Heron (8.04)"
Great -- in 8.04 and even 10.04 I was able to play sounds.  E.g.,

```
cat /usr/share/xemacs21/xemacs-packages/etc/sounds/cuckoo.au > /dev/audio
```

or

```
cat /usr/share/xemacs21/xemacs-packages/etc/sounds/cuckoo.wav > /dev/dsp
```

(This has nothing to do with emacs -- it's just a sound file I happen to have handy.)

HOWTO: "For best results, I recommend all users who are interested in PulseAudio to install the latest release - Karmic Koala (9.10)."
I'm running Trusty Tahr (14.04); /dev/audio and /dev/dsp are gone!

Sure, this works:

```
 padsp tee /dev/dsp < /usr/lib/xemacs/xemacs-packages/etc/sounds/cuckoo.wav > /dev/null
```

but it seems more like a hack/wrapper for legacy code than best practice.

Home Wiki: "Things like transferring the audio to a different machine, changing the sample format or channel count and mixing several sounds into one are easily achieved using a sound server."

OK, how do I transfer audio to a different machine?  Or for that matter, to the same machine?

"A sound server is basically a proxy for your sound applications."
Wonderful.  How can/should a sound application use it?

"You may run into applications that use OSS output (programs looking for /dev/dsp). Ubuntu no longer supports OSS natively, and you should try to switch the program's audio output to something better supported, like ALSA or esound/esd (which pulse emulates very well)."
How would you do that?  How about something that is not emulated, but uses Pulseaudio natively??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is find recipes in a dictionary...  Just use a cookbook!

[Official PulseAudio Documentation](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/)

Or alternatively, have a look at this diagram:

[image: Source: https://rudd-o.com/linux-and-free-software/how-pulseaudio-works]

<sub>[Source](https://rudd-o.com/linux-and-free-software/how-pulseaudio-works)</sub>

Comment: www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/ has more marketing hype for PulseAudio but NO INFORMATION.  E.g. "PulseAudio is however much more advanced and has numerous features."

At least it links to Manuel Amador's diagram and page "How PulseAudio works".  Seems rather vast.

So for practical use, I use this:

`nc -kl 10034 | padsp tee /dev/dsp > /dev/null &`

knowing that I "should try to switch the program's audio output to something better supported"

Comment: @Quigi: thanks for the update.  As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**